# org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver} - Error while reading from the socket

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Thanks all for the oportunity.

I´m trying configure DAS(Analytics) with APIM wso2 Gateway.

Follow bellow the error in log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-24 20:26:04,912] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} -  Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.response:1.1.0 of event bundle with events 200
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.response:1.1.0 present in cache
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:166)
        ... 7 more
TID: [-1] [] [2017-04-24 20:26:19,375] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver} -  Error while reading from the socket.  {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver}
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:928)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:161)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
        ... 11 more
```

Someone can help me in this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is probably with the certificate that is being used to authenticate each other during the handshake. Try this by importing APIM certificate to APIM-Analytics server's client trust store